# Rack: /var/app/current: No such file or directory on Elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Im trying to clone a repository onto the Rails root on an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance

but im experiencing the following error

rb.

```
%x(git clone #{a["clone_url"]} #{Rails.root.join('repos',a["owner"]["login"],a["name"])})
```

/var/app/support/logs/passenger.log

```
2013/05/02 16:26:08 [error] 1741#0: *4 "/var/app/current/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"
(github) Request phase initiated.
(github) Callback phase initiated.
Rack: /var/app/current: No such file or directory - git clone https://github.com/henghonglee/BehaviorTree.git /var/app/current/repos/henghonglee/BehaviorTree
```

I have installed git on the ec2 instance and managed to perform the clone independantly(not using the Rails App).

Answer (score 0):

Should you have done this in '/var/app/ondeck' instead?

You didn't provide when this cloning is to be executed. Just to be safe, do a test if folder exists. You should do this under container_commands, and it's always '/var/app/ondeck', don't mess with current.